# Time column changes into decimal form when imported to MATLAB

Tags: matlab, date, plot, matlab-figure

I have datasets from an xlxs file in Excel which I have to import in MATLAB. The problem is that whenever I import the data, time would always come out as decimal.

So in here, the data in the xlxs file shows the format of HH:MM:SS:

[image]

This is what it looks like in the import-assistant of the MATLAB

[image]

I'm about to generate a line graph for it and this is what it looks like:

[image]

This is the sample code that I have used in order to generate the plot, wherein I wanted the time to not show up in decimal form.

```
datestr(Time,'HH:MM:SS');
title ('Particle Measurement for 02-20-2020 @ UPD')
plot(Time,PM10)
xlabel('Time')
ylabel('Particle Measurement')
hold on
plot(Time,PM1)
hold on
plot(Time,PM25)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Time in MATLAB are [`datenum()`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html) values, which are decimal days since 0 Jan 0000. So the things you see *are* correct times. You can use [`datestr(Time,'HH:mm:ss')`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datestr.html) to get a string for the time, and [`datetick('x','HH:mm')`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetick.html) to get the tick marks on the axis in hours.

The line `datestr(Time,'HH:MM:SS');` in your code is superfluous. MATLAB has to take time to evaluate the date string, and then ... nothing. You don't save the output to a variable, nor do you display it (you suppressed that with the semicolon).

Long story short: use `datenum()` values when plotting, and `datetick()` to get the axis labels correct.

Comment: There are also some quirks (see [`x2mdate`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/finance/x2mdate.html) / [`exceltime`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetime.exceltime.html)) to be aware of when importing serial dates from Excel to MATLAB...

Comment: @Wolfie thanks for the mention. I'd say though that OP doesn't have that particular problem, as the question is "how to change the decimals on the axis to time stamps?". Whether the imported numbers themselves are correct... Well, don't use Windows or Excel I guess :D

Comment: hi! I just want to ask regarding what you have said `datetick('x','HH:mm')` is for hours, if ever I want it time to show per 30 mins 14:30:00, 15:00:00, 15:30:00 what should I do? Thank you! and sorry english is not my first language.

Comment: @KrishnaSantos read the documentation I linked. All date formats which MATLAB offers you are in there. If you have a question of how to create different ticks than the ones MATLAB automatically offers you, that's a different question (and bound to be asked already on Stack Overflow), do a search for that please.